# I keep getting NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java

I have to take two integers on the same line with a space in between, and also take array on same line with space in between.

My input:

```
5 2
1 2 3 4 5
```

My output:

```
3 4 5 1 2
```

My code is:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n, d;
n = s.nextInt();
d = s.nextInt();
int a[] = new int[n];
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    a[j] = s.nextInt();
}
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = s.nextInt();
}
for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
    int temp = a[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[n - 1] = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've formatted this question a bit, but the onus is on *you* to explain to us why this output is incorrect.

Comment: Count how many times you're calling `nextInt()`. Does it match the number of integers you want to read?

Comment: How are you deciding that your output has to start from 3?

Comment: n is no of elements in array and d is how many times u have to rotate

Comment: circular left shift

Comment: Either you closed your `System.in` or you're running your code in an online IDE or some badly working local IDE.

Comment: how should i close system.in?

Comment: why are you reading the array twice?

Comment: Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int b[]=new int[2];
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {b[i]=s.nextInt();}
        int n=b[0],d=b[1];
        int a[]=new int[n];
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {  a[j]=s.nextInt(); }
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        a[i]=s.nextInt();
    }
    for(int j=0;j<d;j++)
    {
        int temp=a[0];
   int i;
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {

             a[i]=a[i+1];

        }
        a[i]=temp;
    }
     for( int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {System.out.print(a[i]+" ");}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you run your code for the input you have in your question, this is your output:

```
3 4 1 2 2
```

The reason you have this incorrect output, instead of your intended output is this for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    a[i] = a[i + 1];
    a[n - 1] = temp;
}
```

Every iteration, you are copying the temporary value into the last slot in the array, instead of doing it just once at the end. This will create duplicate values, like the ones seen in the output. To fix this, simply move the final line of the for loop outside of the for loop, like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    a[i] = a[i + 1];  
}
a[n - 1] = temp;
```

Once you make this change, your program works as you intended, except for the fact that you read in the array twice. I actually removed these lines of code before I ran your code, so I'm not sure if it's causing your NoSuchElement Exception. Get rid of these lines, and your code will work fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = s.nextInt();
}
```